# Why is it so difficult to upvote

Tags: discussion

I recently used this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/331568/14198) to configure a DNS server for my virtual machine network, and I thought the answer went far and above in it's readability and thoroughness.

Why can't I vote for this with rep from a different site? This [answer](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/9253/14198) to a similar question seems to imply that there are trolls who go to extreme lengths to upvote themselves, so I understand the need for some controls. My question, though, is not why can't I vote with no reputation, but why my reputation from a different site (Stack Overflow), can't be ported over to allow me to at least upvote or comment? I can't even post this question on Ask Ubuntu meta!

It is somewhat sad to me that the DNS answer only has a 49 rating (at the time of this post), and I believe that part of that at least is that the reputations from Stack Overflow or Server Fault can't be used to vote.

Comment: nice tag! Once you get at a certain number of points on one site you do get points added on the others. It is a tad hard to get the ball rolling, I agree, but it pushes everyone to at least try and help out others, so there is a method to the madness.

Comment: I'm just curious, why the downvote?

Comment: @pdom That downvote was probably from someone who thinks you did not do enough research before asking your question. Welcome to the community though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just try and get over 200rep in StackOverflow. That way, you will always get the site association bonus of +100 points on any new site to get past these new user restrictions.

For more info, read https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation